# Best way to declare an array of Color32

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am looking for a way to declare an array of Color32 with predefined colors in my script. I would like to define the colors before the Start() function. Currently I am adding everything in my Start() function but it throws errors. What am I doing wrong and what is the best way to declare this?

```
public Color32[] colorListRGBA = new Color32[2];

void Start () {
        colorListRGBA[0] = new Color32 (255, 0, 0, 255);
        colorListRGBA[1] = new Color32 (117, 76, 36, 255);
        colorListRGBA[2] = new Color32 (93, 165, 0, 255);
    }
```

I also tried doing it this way:

```
public Color32[] colorListRGBA = new Color32[] { new Color32 (255, 0, 0, 255), new Color32 (117, 76, 36, 255), new Color32 (93, 165, 0, 255) };

public Text myText;
int indexOfColor = 2;

void Start()
{
   myText.color = colorListRGBA[indexOfColor];
}
```

This throws an error `IndexOutOfRangeException: Index was outside the bounds of the array.`

Comment: `new Color32[] { new Color32(...), new Color32(...), new Color32(...) }`? Or do it in the constructor.

Comment: I did that but when I try to assign it like ```mytext.color = colorListRGBA[0];```, it throws error  ```Index was outside the bounds of the array.``` Why?

Comment: Then there must be difference in what you are showing us and what your are actually doing in your code.

Comment: in the first line, you declared a array with 2 positions, but you are alocating 3 positions, throwing an error.

Comment: ah i got to know the problem, since I had declared colorListRGBA as public and in the beginning I had declared only 2 colors as red, which was the reason the colors were not changing and also was throwing errors.

Comment: in the first line, you declared an array of 2 positions, but you are trying to allocate 3 positions in this array. Fix your code:  first line must be  public Color32[] colorListRGBA = new Color32[3]

Comment: in such a case, i wish we could reset the array when "playing" the application.

Comment: Declaring a public variable will have Unity serialize it in the editor. If you modify the array in the editor, it will override the array you define in your class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Declaring a public variable will have Unity serialize it in the editor. If you modify the array in the editor, it will override the array you define in your class.

If you wish to prevent this, using C# auto-properties will prevent Unity from serializing it, but will not give you access to the variable in the editor.

```
public Color32[] ColorListRGBA { get; set; } = new Color32[] { new Color32 (255, 0, 0, 255), new Color32 (117, 76, 36, 255), new Color32 (93, 165, 0, 255) };
```

Answer (score 1):

In the first line, you declared an array of 2 positions, but you are trying to allocate 3 positions in this array. Fix your code: first line must be:

`public Color32[] colorListRGBA = new Color32[3]`